# Tensorflow Handpose model offline loading

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to download the Tensorflow's handpose model files for running offline.

So, i have downloaded the Handpose Model files from here.
https://tfhub.dev/mediapipe/tfjs-model/handskeleton/1/default/1

But, how can we use these files offline and predict in javascript and as well as on the react-Native code.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? There's a nice example on the packages npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow-models/handpose.

Comment: Yes, I tried the code inside the documentation, but it does not work. below is the code, i used on the model.json file.

const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('/models/model.json');

Answer (score 0):

Just change all urls in the hanpose package to point to the url where you put your model ( in your localhost/public_dir)
that works well for me :)

Comment: Are you using react?

Comment: Yes ? Why ? If you are using react, I suggest you to fork the handpose repository packages and change the url in it to point to your local  directory.

Comment: I’m using webpack and react but webpack cannot load the unique Tensorflow file types. Did you run into this?

Comment: No I didn't run into that.

Comment: If you check the handpose package for react , you will see that there are some urls that point to an oline ressources to download the model. So you need to change those URLs to somthing like "http://localhost:300/yourHandposeModel.xxx" . Be  sure to test your url in a browser and that you get a download of the model running. So you need to put the model in your public dir of your local server

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to do this because of filetypes that appear to be unique to tensorflow that webpack is unable to bundle. Anyone found a solution for this?